# Looping through divs to define parent heights

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

There are multiple sections. Each section has multiple tabs. I want to get the first tab height (.tab-content) and apply its height to the section it is in (.tab). This needs to happen to each section individually - hence the loop. The loop doesn't seem to engage currently and the very first height on the .tab-content is getting applied to all the sections. Why is my loop not working?

**Live Example**: https://staging.123innovation.co.uk/careers/faq

**JS**

```
    function tabParentHeight() {

$(".tabs").each(function() {

  var ph = $(this).outerHeight();
  $(this).find('.tab-content:first').css('min-height', 0);
  var ch = $(this).find('.tab-content:first').outerHeight();

  if (ch > ph) {
    $(this).css({
      'height': ch + 'px'
    });
  }
});

}


$(document).ready(function () {


// TABS

// Run Tab Height
tabParentHeight();

$('section a').click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).addClass('active');
  $(this).siblings().removeClass('active');

  var ph = $(this).parent().height();
  var ch = $(this).next().height();

  if (ch > ph) {
    $(this).parent().css({
      'height': ch + 'px'
    });
  } else {
    $(this).parent().css({
      'height': 'auto'
    });
  }
});

});


$(window).resize(function() {
  // Run Tab Height
  tabParentHeight();
});

$(document).resize(function() {
  // Run Tab Height
  tabParentHeight();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<section class="tab">

              <a class="tab-link link pointer blue hover-teal no-underline d tab-link w-33-ns pb3 ba bl-0 bt-0 br-0 b--dotted b--black-30 db relative active" target="_blank">
              <span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-caret-down blue teal rm-90"></i></span>
              Title One
              </a>

              <div id="tab-21" class="tab-content w-two-thirds-ns h-auto pt3 pb2 pl3 pl5-ns">
                  <h3 class="dn db-ns">Content One</h3>
                  <p>Content goes here</p>
              </div>



              <a class="tab-link link pointer blue hover-teal no-underline d tab-link w-33-ns pb3 ba bl-0 bt-0 br-0 b--dotted b--black-30 db relative" target="_blank">
              <span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-caret-down blue teal rm-90"></i></span>
              Title One
              </a>

              <div id="tab-21" class="tab-content w-two-thirds-ns h-auto pt3 pb2 pl3 pl5-ns">
                  <h3 class="dn db-ns">Content Two</h3>
                  <p>Content goes here</p>
              </div>



              <a class="tab-link link pointer blue hover-teal no-underline d tab-link w-33-ns pb3 ba bl-0 bt-0 br-0 b--dotted b--black-30 db relative" target="_blank">
              <span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-caret-down blue teal rm-90"></i></span>
              Title One
              </a>

              <div id="tab-21" class="tab-content w-two-thirds-ns h-auto pt3 pb2 pl3 pl5-ns">
                  <h3 class="dn db-ns">Content Three</h3>
                  <p>Content goes here</p>
              </div>


</section>



<section class="tab list ml2 pl0 tf w-100 h-auto db relative">


              <a class="tab-link link pointer blue hover-teal no-underline d tab-link w-33-ns pb3 ba bl-0 bt-0 br-0 b--dotted b--black-30 db relative active" target="_blank">
              <span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-caret-down blue teal rm-90"></i></span>
              Title One
              </a>

              <div id="tab-21" class="tab-content w-two-thirds-ns h-auto pt3 pb2 pl3 pl5-ns">
                  <h3 class="dn db-ns">Content One</h3>
                  <p>Content goes here</p>
              </div>



              <a class="tab-link link pointer blue hover-teal no-underline d tab-link w-33-ns pb3 ba bl-0 bt-0 br-0 b--dotted b--black-30 db relative" target="_blank">
              <span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-caret-down blue teal rm-90"></i></span>
              Title One
              </a>

              <div id="tab-21" class="tab-content w-two-thirds-ns h-auto pt3 pb2 pl3 pl5-ns">
                  <h3 class="dn db-ns">Content Two</h3>
                  <p>Content goes here</p>
              </div>



              <a class="tab-link link pointer blue hover-teal no-underline d tab-link w-33-ns pb3 ba bl-0 bt-0 br-0 b--dotted b--black-30 db relative" target="_blank">
              <span class="fa-li"><i class="fas fa-caret-down blue teal rm-90"></i></span>
              Title One
              </a>

              <div id="tab-21" class="tab-content w-two-thirds-ns h-auto pt3 pb2 pl3 pl5-ns">
                  <h3 class="dn db-ns">Content Three</h3>
                  <p>Content goes here</p>
              </div>


</section>
```

Comment: Can you share the html? It would help to see the structure and find out which elements are associated with the classes .tab and .tab-content.

Comment: Hi I have added the full JS and HTML

Comment: Looks like you have a typo in your identifier. Shouldn't it be $(".tabs") instead of $(".tab") ?

Comment: tab class fixed - still not looping though

Comment: why do you need to change the height tho? isn't it automatic?

Comment: The height needs adjusting as the content inside is absolutely positioned.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how exactly those elements are generated but for some reason it is causing the issue. all tab contents have `min-height: 100%` attribute and since you added you're script, all of them are having the same height as the first one.

Anyway to fix the issue, you can remove the `min-height: 100%` in `tab-content` class in your css or do something like this in your script:

```
$('.tabs').each(function() {
    $(this).find('.tab-content').css('min-height', 0);
    $(this).outerHeight($(this).find('.tab-content').outerHeight());
});
```

---

Edit: can you replace your tabParentHeight() function to:

```js
$(".tabs").each(function() {

  var ph = $(this).outerHeight();
  $(this).find('.tab-content:first').css('min-height', 0);
  var ch = $(this).find('.tab-content:first').outerHeight();

  if (ch > ph) {
    $(this).css({
      'height': ch + 'px'
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Removing min-height 100% doesn't do anything really.

Comment: The real issue is the loop - the first height is still getting applied to all sections. The loop isn't applying the unique first height to its own section.

Comment: So each .tab is outputting: height: 1116px; when .tab one would be height: 1116px; and tab two would be height: 530px; for example

Comment: please see edit. you can reconfigure your code base on that. the goal is to remove the min-height: 100% of the tab-content because for some reason it inherits the height of the first one. I suspect they are all being generated in the same div before being distributed to their respective sections.

Comment: I removed the min-height totally from the css. It wasn't required. I have pasted in your updated JS and again I'm still getting the same height across ALL the sections.

Comment: that's weird. if you try to run either of the script above in your console in your website, it fixes the issue.

Comment: Are you sure you initialized tabParentHeight() on document ready?

Comment: Yes it runs on document ready - this is where I wish StackOverflow had a skype like feature.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/192040/discussion-between-dan-lee-and-acd).

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't right now anymore mate. I'm just burning time here in office coz i'm not doing anything and my shift's about to end. :/